# newly created Chromebook OS emulator crashes on startup

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, chromebook

I recently created a Chromebook OS emulator on Android Studio with the help of https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/emulator , however, it crashes on launch and getting following errors

```
12:12 PM    Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64: -usbdevice tablet: '-usbdevice' is deprecated, please use '-device usb-...' instead

    12:12 PM    Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile: /Users/sshinde/.android/emulator-grpc.cer security will be disabled.

    12:12 PM    Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554

    12:12 PM    Emulator: virto-goldfish-pipe fatal error: init:469: Could not get virtio gpu ops!

    12:12 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

[image]

I also tried updating Android studio to latest version 3.6.1 but the emulator still crashes. Is there any other way to test android app on Chrome OS or how to resolve these errors? P.S I don't own an actual device

Answer (score 21):

Appears to be a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147557436) with the emulator binary.

Per the tracker, download the older version of the emulator and replace it within your Android SDK folder. I was able to verify this working on MacOS.

- Windows https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-6031357.zip
- Linux https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-6031357.zip
- MacOS https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-6031357.zip

Edit: I should mention it's only working via CLI for me, not through Android Studio `emulator -avd Pixelbook_beta_API_25`

Comment: After trying this answer, I ran into an alert which says the developer cannot be verified and the emulator does not run. This is due to a security feature of MacOS Catalina. I was able to get around the alert and I wrote my solution down in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62879932/11506363.