# Chrome OS Emulator is crashing on startup

Tags: android, crash, emulation, google-chrome-os

I tried to debug my Android app on Chrome OS emulator in Android studio. This is the tutorial I followed:
https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/emulator

The problem is, it crashes on startup. If I try to launch it via terminal, I get this output:

```
./emulator -avd Pixelbook_beta_API_25
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
emulator: WARNING: Running on a system with less than 6 logical cores. Setting number of virtual cores to 1
qemu-system-x86_64: -usbdevice tablet: '-usbdevice' is deprecated, please use '-device usb-...' instead
virto-goldfish-pipe fatal error: init:475: Could not get virtio gpu ops!
Abort trap: 6
```

When googling I found only this question, but top solution didn't help me because macOS Catalina spits out a message "Developer can't be verified"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60819386/9815389

About the environment: I am using macOS 10.15.4, Android Studio 3.6.3. Settings for the emulator are standard, except for the ram which I bumped up to 2048 MB as Google documentation recommends

Answer (score 2):

I am also using a Mac running Catalina and face the same problem when I try to start the emulator, even when done from the command line. Specifically, I get an alert which states: “qemu-system-x86_64” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

The solution to this problem is simply to allow the "qemu-system-x86_64" program to run. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Try to run the emulator again and wait for the alert to be shown.
2. Click "Cancel" on the alert.
3. Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General.
4. Near the bottom you should see a header called "Allow apps downloaded from:". Make sure you have the "App Store and identified developers" option selected.
5. You should see an "Allow Anyway" button to the right of some text which says: "qemu-system-x86_64" was blocked from use because it is not from an identified developer. Click the "Allow Anyway" button.
6. Try running the emulator again.
7. You should see the same alert as before, except now there should be an "Open" button. Click the "Open" button.
8. You might see more (possibly a lot) "cannot verify" alerts without "Open" buttons for different program files which the emulator uses. If this is the case, repeat steps 2 through 8 until the emulator runs correctly. It may take awhile, but eventually the emulator will run.

Here's a screenshot of my Security & Privacy Page:

[image: Settings Page]

Comment: I tried this. It worked well except that I also had to close and reopen the Terminal window.