# How do you create a Chrome OS emulator?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, google-chrome-os, androidappsonchromeos

What are the steps needed to create a Chrome OS virtual device in Android Studio (or from the command line)?

I see that you can choose "Chrome OS Device" in the Device Manager, but when I choose that I get an error that says "No system images available."

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I could find is to create a desktop Android Virtual Device that runs Android 12.

To do this, choose Device Manager -> Create Device -> Desktop in the canary version of Android Studio.

Source: https://chromeos.dev/en/posts/desktop-avd-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Desktop AVD](https://chromeos.dev/en/posts/desktop-avd-in-android-studio#try-out-the-desktop-avd) available with AndroidStudio Electric Eel canary version to test out your android apps for Chrome OS. Note that this is not available with the latest stable version Dolphin 2021.3.1.

Although, from your question, I understand you want to have a "ChromeOS virtual device". There used to be a 'Pixelbook_beta_API_25' AVD but it is not available anymore (saying this because an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147557436) that needs to be addressed in the PixelBook emulator has been marked obsolete by the Google team). If you are not using an M1 Mac, maybe try your hand with the downloadable emulators of Pixelbook [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60819386/3138195)

If you are just trying to develop an android app for ChromeOS, what I would suggest is to use the Electric Eel canary one because at the end of the day Android apps are run inside a container environment (previously called ARC - Android Runtime from Chrome). Hope this helps.